# Can I declare the ArrayList in this way?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
Iterable<Board> theNeighbors = new ArrayList<Board>();
```

Here is my initialization for the `ArrayList` theNeighbors, which uses the interafce `Iterable` for declaration. However, as I use method `add()` to the variable I just built, the compiler alerts

> Board.java:78: error: cannot find symbol          theNeighbors.add(nb);
>                         ^
>   symbol:   method add(Board)
>   location: variable theNeighbors of type Iterable

What makes it happen? In another case while I use

```
List<Board> theNeighbors = new ArrayList<Board>();
```

The `add()` method works well. Is it true that the interface you choose for the declaration should always have the method you want to call later?

Comment: Yes, the variable named theNeighbors is an Iterable, which does not have method add(). However, if you want to use both Iterable declaration and add() method you could use ((List) theNeighbors).add(nb);

Comment: Does java use this mechanism to prevent you from initialising this variable with another implementation which doesnt

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) for the `Iterable` interface, you will see, as you mentioned, that the `add()` method does not exist.

> Is it true that the interface you choose for the declaration should always have the method you want to call later?

The interface you choose should have all the behaviors of the object you plan to instantiate and use.

When you declare your `ArrayList` like this:

```
Iterable<Board> theNeighbors = new ArrayList<Board>();
```

the JVM treats `theNeighbors` as an `Iterable` and therefore cannot find the `add()` method.  On the other hand, if you define your `ArrayList` this way:

```
List<Board> theNeighbors = new ArrayList<Board>();
```

then the JVM *can* find an `add()` method since all types of `List` have this method (and behavior).